# Import whole repo from gogs to gitlab server

Tags: gitlab, gogs

I have task to migrate whole repository from our Gogs server to newly installed Gitlab server!

Before considering to forget my repositories history (comments, issues, etc...), do one know of a way to export a repository data from a Gogs server to Gitlab Server ?

I just failed to found anything on the documentation for exporting/migrating the whole project data (not just the git repository and its wiki).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native way of export/importing comments and issues and pull requests from gogs to GitLab, considering they are mainly database elements, that would need to be converted from one schema (in Gogs database) to another (your GitLab server database).

Even for simple Git repos which are forks of other repositories, restoring the fork link is not trivial (but possible: see [this GitLab thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/migrating-from-gogs-to-gitlab-importing-repos/9144))

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do what was done here: https://github.com/shafferjohn/migrate-gogs-to-gitlab/blob/master/migrate.py

```
git clone --mirror <gogs_repo_git_url> <dirname>
pushd <dirname>
git remote set-url origin <gitlab_repo_git_url>
git push --mirror
popd
```